# Its possible to read the value of a cookie in a resque´s job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Environment:

```
devise
devise-async
```

Problem

I am trying to pass params to the confirmation_instructions method.

```
def confirmation_instructions(user)
  @code = cookie[:utm]
  devise_mail(user, :confirmation_instructions)
end
```

It returns the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<Devise::Mailer:0x007fcba4fdd208>
```

I try to add ApplicationHelper to the mailer and create a method in applicationHelper that returns the value of the cookie but it fails too.

How can i pass other params instead of user to the method ?
Or how can i read the value of a cookie ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't read a cookie from within a Resque job.  It's completely detached from the browser at that point.  You'd want to read the cookie before you queue the job and then pass the value of the cookie to the job.